# Modal/Dialog is opening at the bottom of the screen, and not behaving properly

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Like the question says, my dialog is popping up on the bottom of the screen, rather than in the middle.  It also does not close on click, but rather whenever I hit escape.  The rest of the page is also not disabled or grayed out, so I can stack them up (see below).

[image]

I'm using basically the exact same code as in the example

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {MdDialog, MdDialogRef} from '@angular/material';

@Component({
    selector: 'dialog-overview-example',
    template: '<button md-button (click)="openDialog()">Open dialog</button>'
})
export class DialogOverviewExample {
    constructor(public dialog: MdDialog) {}

    public openDialog(): void {
        this.dialog.open(BasicDialog);
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'dialog-overview-example-dialog',
    template: "<p> Hi, I'm a dialog! </p>",
})
export class BasicDialog {}
```

I think my imports are correct, but here they are:

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, {useHash: true}),
    MdDialogModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    CommonModule
],
```

Note that there is no error or warning in the console, and I have tried disabling css.

Anyone seen this before?

Comment: you have some duplicate imports in your module. I'm not sure how Angular behaves with this, but since you have `BrowserAnimationsModule` imported twice, could you try cleaning it up and see what happens?

Comment: Good catch, but unfortunately, that did not fix the issue.  Thanks.

Comment: Just as another heads up, you have `FormsModule` imported twice.

Answer (score 28):

Turns out the issue was with how I was importing css.  Previously I was importing into an scss file:

```scss
@import '../../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/purple-green.css';
```

I did import the stylings, which is why I thought that was enough, however; apparently, you need to import the css in your `index.html`:

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

So there it is.  In retrospect, it should have been obvious from the beginning, but like I said, I assumed it was correctly imported because the style was actually imported.  Also, I tried importing a minified version, and that also did not work.

Comment: I think that if you use the address as specified below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/49518190/540061), that you'll find it would work. This worked for me.

Answer (score 19):

The issue is not importing/including the angular material theme.

To solve this issue, kindly add the code in your global css, if using cli, then add to your styles.css

@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";

Answer (score 9):

**I prefer this method in my angular.json file**

```
"styles": [
              "src/styles/styles.less",             
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"              
            ],
```

Answer (score 8):

in the index.html add the following link to angular material

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">
```